# Hiding and showing an element via visibility:hidden/visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got 2 div-boxes which should show/hide when clicking other 2 div-boxes. And I want the div's keep their space so it wouldn't ruin the DOM, so I guess `.toggle()` is out of question.

I tried this with no luck:

```
$('#red, #pink').click(function() {
// Based on the id property of the clicked element 

// this selects #reddef or #pinkdef element
if($('#' + this.id + 'def').is(":visible")) {
$('#' + this.id + 'def').css('visibility','hidden');} 

else if($('#' + this.id + 'def').is(":hidden")) {
$('#' + this.id + 'def').css('visibility','visible')}

});
```

So if I click `#red` then `#reddef` disappears while keeping the space. But when I click again nothing happens. I guess there's just a little thing I'm misssing atm, but can't figure out what.

Comment: try using jquery `$('#' + this.id + 'def').hide()` `$('#' + this.id + 'def').show()` instead ;)

Comment: You are overly complicating things

Comment: Hmm, I thought both `.hide()` and `.show()` affect the same way as `.toggle()`. They both change the `display` attribute? which is what I don't want.

Comment: @user2829315, give a try, then decide

Comment: @DaveA From the docs for `.toggle()`: `The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no animation, by changing the CSS display property.` This isn't what the OP wanted.

Comment: @winterblood, animation? I missed that. In fact, reading original post, I still don't see it. In fact, the only ref to word animation is in your comment :(

Comment: @DaveA What I meant with that quote was that the original post explicitly states that the hidden elements should still take up physical space in the layout - changing an element's `display` property will add/remove it from the layout, while changing the `visibility` property won't.

Comment: @winterblood, OIC. Avoiding animation. Yes, I missed that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) for the `:hidden` selector:

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

I would recommend instead to add/remove a class as this is easier to test like so:

```
if($('#' + this.id + 'def').hasClass('visHidden')) {
    $('#' + this.id + 'def').removeClass('visHidden')
}
else {
    $('#' + this.id + 'def').addClass('visHidden');
}
```

Where your CSS would be:

```
.visHidden {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Use `.toggleClass()`.

Comment: @Barmar I generally don't use, and don't recommend using, `.toggleClass()` without knowing 100% that the class will not be modified elsewhere in code, otherwise you can quite easily get out of phase class toggling.

Comment: If you're trying to keep the class in sync with a variable, that's a good approach. But `toggleClass()` does exactly what you wrote in your answer: if the element has the class, it removes it, otherwise it adds it.

Comment: I decided to go with the `.toggleClass()` since it suits for me better. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rYYPb/

```
$('#red, #pink').on('click', function() {

    var $def = $('#' + this.id + 'def');
    if ($def.css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
        $def.css('visibility', 'visible')
    }
    else {
        $def.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }

});
```

Like winterblood said, `visibility: hidden` is still "visible" by jQuery's standards. So instead you can check whether it actually has the `hidden` style.